# Want to skip Background urls in Extent Reporting

Tags: karate, extentreports

I am generating a extent report in Karate where I am displaying url and their status. I want to only show main urls which are in scenario in report and not the background urls. Does anyone know how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read and understand this section in the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#report-verbosity

One easy way to do this is call another feature in the `Background` and in that feature have this tag:

```
@report=false
Feature:

Scenario:
# some background stuff
```

Comment: Thanks Peter! But I want to get that url in extent report when that was running as main scenario. I don't want to get that url when it was running as called feature in background, because that is displaying a single url as many times as it is called in any other feature

Comment: @Swati that is exactly what I'm telling you. call that URL in the called feature. if that doesn't answer your question, please assume that this is not supported by karate and contribute code if needed